# How to assign table values to original data in R?

Tags: r, frequency

I'm quiet new in working with R, so sorry for any stupid question.

Usually I have to deal with really big data sets.
I want to have the number of observations for each observation, without making the original dataset smaller.
I have a very small example for my problem:

```
Observations<-c("A1","A2","B1","B3","B3","C1","C1","C1","C1","C2","C3","C3","C3")
```

With table I get:

```
> table(Obsevations)
Observations
A1 A2 B1 B3 C1 C2 C3 
 1  1  1  2  4  1  3
```

But what I actually want is:

```
A1 A2 B1 B3 B3 C1 C1 C1 C1 C2 C3 C3 C3
 1  1  1  2  2  4  4  4  4  1  3  3  3
```

Is there an elegant and fast way to do this in big data sets without any loops?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `rep` here

```
tbl <- table(Observations)
rep(tbl, tbl)
#  A1 A2 B1 B3 B3 C1 C1 C1 C1 C2 C3 C3 C3 
#  1  1  1  2  2  4  4  4  4  1  3  3  3
```

Based on the example, another option is `ave`

```
ave(seq_along(Observations), Observations, FUN = length)
```

Comment: Also `table(Observations)[Observations]`, although they may not want to deal with the table object as output.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really fast and exactly what I need! It works perfectly.